# How to conditionally render in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, render

I'm trying to conditional rendering in an Electron-React-Typescript app.

This is the code:

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react'
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'

const imgViewer = (file: File) => {
  const obj_url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  return(
    <div>
      <img src={obj_url} />
    </div>
  )
}
const pdfViewer = (file: File) => {
  const obj_url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="embed-responsive">
        <iframe src={obj_url}></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function MyDropzone() {
  let fileType;
  let imgF;
  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()

      reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
      reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
      reader.onload = () => {
        const binaryStr = reader.result
        console.log("binaryStr", binaryStr)
      }
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
      fileType = file.type

      console.log("file.type: ", file.type);

      if (fileType.includes("image/")) {
        console.log("FileType: image");
        return imgViewer(file);
      }

      if (fileType.includes("/pdf")) {
        console.log("FileType: pdf");
        return pdfViewer(file);
      }
    })
  }, [])

  const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({onDrop})

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How to render in MyDropzone the image and the pdf files, calling the proper imgViewer or the pdfViewer ?
I've set the two functions, but I do not know how to conditionally render.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: Conditional render explained in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Thanks @DennisVash My situation is not that simple.I'm going to write a better post

Comment: @NishargShah I'm going to write a better post. Thank you anyway for answering